# How to pronounce "Burali-Fòrti" in Italian?

Tags: pronunciation

In logic, we have Burali-Fòrti's paradox which is named by [Cesare Burali-Fòrti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cesare_Burali-Forti).

Now I need to know the exact pronunciation of "Burali-Fòrti" (of which I only know the overall pronunciation) to translate it into Chinese from the sound.

So is there any native Italian to know how to pronounce "Burali-Fòrti"? If so, please use the [International Phonetic Alphabet for Italian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/Italian) to show how to pronounce it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply /buˌrali'fɔrti/, I'd say. Do other people agree?

Comment: @DaG Looks good to me

Comment: @DaG Maybe you can write it as an answer, just to give closure to the question.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Yes, sorry. The OP did so, fortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply

/'tʃezare buˌrali'fɔrti/,

or

/'tʃezare bu'rali 'fɔrti/ if one prefers to keep the two parts of the surname distinct.

Comment: Sorry for not having put that as an actual answer before: thanks. Let me throw in, as a bonus, the pronunciation of “Cesare”: /'tʃezare/.

Comment: The secondary accent can also be a primary one, that is, uttering two distinct words, depending on the speaker's preferences.